# Can we conclude a subspace is Invariant by using circular convolution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a subspace $C$ of $R^{n}$.  How can I prove the following?

$C$ is invariant under $\pi$ if for any two vectors $a,b \in C$, $a\circledast b \in C$.

where $\pi :R^{n} \rightarrow R^{n}$ defined by $\pi(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})=(x_{2},x_{3},...,x_{n}, x_{1})$

$\circledast $: circular convolution

Comment: This may sound silly but can you give the definition of circular convolution of two arbitrary vectors in $R^n$? Wikipedia seems to only give a definition for functions

Comment: $c_{i}= \sum_{j} a_{j} b_{i-j}$ where $i,j= 0 ~to~ n-1$

Comment: I find myself yearning to translate this into a question about the space of functions on a cyclic group of order $n$, where "circular convolution" is literal convolution-of-functions-on-a-group... Then $C$ is the translation effect on functions on the group (by generator $1$ of the group). Yes, group-algebra-invariant subspaces are the same as convolution-algebra-invariant subspaces... but this isn't quite what you're asking? Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question (the set of vectors can be a subset of an invariant space, but also of a noninvariant superspace thereof), seems reasonable to look at this in the Fourier domain, where pi-invariant spaces are coordinate aligned and convolution is coordinate-wise multiplication.

Comment: @YoavKallus, noninvariant superspace?

Comment: @paulgarrett Would you please, explain more? how can we conclude C is invariant if a,b and their circular convolution belong to C?

Comment: Is C generated by {a,b,c,d,...}? Otherwise I'm not sure how we're supposed to conclude something about C from a property of {a,b,c,d,...}. There can be two spaces, C_1 and C_2, both of which contain {a,b,c,d,...}, one with the desired property and one without.

Comment: Or is {a,b,c,d,..} supposed to represent an arbitrary subset of C? If so, what is the role of c, d, etc.?

Comment: @YoavKallus: Only the OP can settle this for sure, but my guess is that the first line of the question should be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't true. I follow Paul's suggestion of taking (discrete) Fourier transforms $\widehat{x}(\zeta)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x_j\zeta^j$, $\zeta^n=1$. Then a subspace closed under convolution becomes one closed under pointwise multiplication, and $\widehat{\pi x} =\zeta^{-1}\widehat{x}$.

Now the subspace defined by the condition that $\widehat{x}(\zeta_1)=\widehat{x}(\zeta_2)$ is closed under multiplication, but won't be left invariant by multiplication by $\zeta$. We can make this more concrete, also to confirm that we can obtain real valued examples: Take $n=4$ and the subspace generated by (taking linear combinations of convolution powers of) $x=(1,-1,1,1)$. Notice that $\widehat{x}(1)=\widehat{x}(-1)=2$.

Alternatively, we can forget how we got this and just check directly that the subspace generated by $x$ is spanned by $e_1,x,e_3$, and this is not invariant under $\pi$.

Comment: Shorter still:  "C = {(x0, x1, x2, -x1 )} is closed under circular convolution but not invariant under pi"

Comment: @christian, thanks for your response. May I ask you to explain your examples more?

Comment: @MattF. May I ask you to explain it more?

Comment: @Niki, what part of the comment needs explanation -- the definition of C, why it is closed under convolution, why it is not invariant under pi, or how this answers the question?

Comment: @MattF. why it is closed under convolution, why it is not invariant under pi?

Comment: @Niki, those questions would be better suited to Math StackExchange.

Comment: @Niki: If you don't like the first part about the FTs, then you can just check the claims directly: work out $x$, $x*x$, $x*x*x$, etc., show that the subspace $C$ spanned by these vectors has basis $e_1,e_3,x$, and finally observe that this $C$ is not $\pi$ invariant, but it is closed under convolution by construction (or check that directly, too).

Comment: @MattF. Sorry that I ask this question again; why your example should be closed under circular convolution? the answer of circular convolution is: (x0^2+x2^2-2x1^2, 2x0x1-2x1x2, 2x0x2+2x1^2, 2x1x2-2x0x1) which is not closed

Comment: @christian Sorry, still I am not convinced with your answer.  How can we prove F(\pi x) = \zeta F(x)? why we defined condition F(x(zeta1))=F(x(zeta2))? you consider x=(1,-1,1,1) which is not closed under circular convolution, that would be okay? and in the frequency domain, it will be X=(2,2,2,2) which is not closed under multiplication, that is correct?

Comment: @christian about the second example, direct one, why $e_{1}, e_{3}, x$ are basis? why C in noninvariant? C is equal to $e_{1}, e_{3}, x$?